# What are the possible reasons for SQL Dumps? Tried using DBCC CHECKDB but with no success

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008

I have an SQL Server 2008 (RTM) instance installed on Windows Server 2003. It has around 30 databases. The configuration was running fine for a year, until today when SQL Server stopped unexpectedly and my windows showed the infamous BSOD(Blue screen of death).

I checked all logs (Application, System, SQL Error Logs etc) and found that SQL had been generating dumps for past 2 months. (SQLDump0001,SQLDump0002,SQLDump0003,... upto SQLDump0060 (60 SQLDumps)).

I tried using DBCC CHECKDB and found certain "inconsistency errors" in 2-3 databases. But when I again used DBCC CHECKDB on the same databases, but on a different server, there were no errors.

Can anyone come up with possible reasons for this? Is it a hardware issue? Possibly the RAM? Since this happened today on my production server, I shifted to a backup server temporarily. But need to fix is asap.

Even the minutest of help is appreciated!

Comment: SQL Dump is the backup of the databases and the data on them sometimes generated from a server crash. This link discusses further.Also this could be caused by no space issue on your drive. See the following links http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1810/out-of-space-on-the-c-drive-of-your-sql-server-and-ways-to-reclaim-disk-space/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512593/what-is-sql-dump-for

Comment: There is enough space. I checked on that

Comment: What do you mean the same databases, but on different servers?  Did you restore from a backup, or did you create a new backup (from Source) and restore it, then run CHECKDB?

Comment: I copied the MDF & LDF files to another server for checking if my DBs were corrupt. But there were no errors in CHECKDB.

Comment: SQL Dumps certainly are not backups. They are problem reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!! It took me a day although.

I am using an IBM x3200 machine which supports DDR2 PC2-5300(E) RAMs where E stands for ECC.

Unfortunately, during a hardware upgrade 2 months back, my team upgraded the x3200 machine with a DDR2 PC2-5300(U) RAM (non-ECC) and not DDR2 PC2-5300(E) RAM. And it stands that, ECC supported motherboards generally do not support non-ECC RAMS.

As a result, SQL Dumping started and kept increasing each day. Finally my OS crashed and BSOD appeared. I had to immediately change the RAM and format the server. It works now.